# Derivative of the parameter in variation formula

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

The formula for a **global** vertical variation of a field w.r.t an infinitesimal parameter epsilon can be expressed as $$\delta_\epsilon\phi^a={\phi^a}'(x)-\phi^a(x) = \epsilon\frac {\partial\phi^a}{\partial\epsilon}$$

The formula for a **local** vertical variation is $$\delta_\epsilon\phi^a=G^a\epsilon+G^{a,\mu}d_\mu\epsilon$$ for some arbitrary functions $$G^a, G^{a,\mu}$$.

The first formula comes from the expansion of the transformed field, but how is the second one derived? And how it can contain a spacetime derivative since by definition of the vertical transformation we're keeping the coordinates fixed.